# How to retrieve mysql table and output to xml but using variable in URL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

This script can pull data from mysql table then export it to xml

How can i retrieve msgid by passing variable to the URL and output to XML

This should be easy but i cant seem to get it right.

It should be like that:

http://localhost/test.php?msgid=d503dba6-44b8-4ba0-ae9a-8d6743a914ee

```
<data>
 <acceptreport>
  <id>4692</id>
  <username>test1</username>
  <msgid>d503dba6-44b8-4ba0-ae9a-8d6743a914ee</msgid>
  <sender>TOPS</sender>
  <receiver>523452345</receiver>
  <acceptedfordeliverytime>2016-06-21 09:04:16</acceptedfordeliverytime>
  <deliveredtohandsettime>2016-06-21 09:04:00</deliveredtohandsettime>
  <operator>AIRLINK</operator>
  <status>deliveredtohandset</status>
 </acceptreport>
</data>
```

This is the script

```
<?php
//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "192.168.1.1";
$config['mysql_user'] = "test";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "pass#word";
$config['db_name']    = "testdb";
$config['table_name'] = "box";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

/**
 * @param mysql_resource - $queryResult - mysql query result
 * @param string - $rootElementName - root element name
 * @param string - $childElementName - child element name
 */
function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{
    $xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n";
    $xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";

    while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult))
    {
        /* Create the first child element */
        $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";

        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++)
        {
            $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i);

            /* The child will take the name of the table column */
            $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";

            /* We set empty columns with NULL, or you could set
                it to '0' or a blank. */
            if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
                $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName;
            else
                $xmlData .= "null";

            $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">";
        }
        $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">";
    }
    $xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">";

    return $xmlData;
}

/* Sql query */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, msgid, sender, receiver, acceptedfordeliverytime, deliveredtohandsettime, operator, status FROM outbox  WHERE username = 'top2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

/* If you want to process the returned xml rather than send it
    to the browser, remove the below line.
*/
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo sqlToXml($result, "data", "acceptreport");
?>
```

Comment: What you exactly required?

Comment: I want to use a variable in my url to query mysql table then out it to xml

Comment: Add this line in child tag :   $xmlData .= "<msgid>".$_REQUEST['msgid']."</msgid>";

Comment: am getting this. error error on line 2 at column 400: Opening and ending tag mismatch: acceptreport line 0 and data

Comment: Can you please show me those error?

Comment: $xmlData .= "<msgid>".$_REQUEST['msgid']."</msgid>";  $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; instead of $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">";

Comment: It is better to use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST, also you should check first if the variable is set

Comment: Its not updating all the xml output. only added this at the end <msgid>7c8e3c5c-fe4c-40d6-8966-068197ab3d61</msgid>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong variable to get the data in the where clause.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, msgid, sender, receiver, acceptedfordeliverytime, deliveredtohandsettime, operator, status FROM outbox  WHERE username = 'burs2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

You need to pass in the `username` in the url to get your dynamic data

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, msgid, sender, receiver, acceptedfordeliverytime, deliveredtohandsettime, operator, status FROM outbox  WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

You're not pulling data by the `msgid`. The url you should be calling should be the following

```
http://localhost/test.php?username=test1
```

Comment: Never insert a variable direct into a mysql-statement! Please check the varibale first of valid content

Comment: I need to pull by msgid not username. Which variable i shoud check?

Comment: then you should change your query where clause to search by msgid instead of the username